# How do I collect data from multiple g-shet workbooks using Form Responses (URL's)?

Tags: database, google-sheets, append, google-forms

I've tried =query(importrange()) but the issue is that I need to append previous data, not overwrite it once a new form submission comes in.

[Here is the Database sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nuO1iUsOY_5WYVp5lQ3_BxsSgElGFA7rCrFH_ceSFVY/edit#gid=1964794178) with my current "solution" which is to add a new range at the end of the previous one each time a new submission is made (see RouteData!A2 & A8; StopData! A2 & A54). This is far from ideal as there will be 12-15 submissions a day, indefinitely.

Each form submission is a URL link to a Route Sheet that contains up to 12 routes/day. Each Route can contain up to 15 stops/day. I have 15 locations that make deliveries each day and each location will submit a route workbook daily, this increasing the database size very quickly (more so on the StopData! tab, then the RouteData! tab).

The data I am trying to collect is on the StopData & RouteData tabs inside the form submission URL's. That info can be populated to the corresponding RouteData & StopData tab on the database sheet.

I am open to other ways to get this data collected each day. The current solution of having the workbook URL submitted (via form) and then the Stop/Route data accessed that way is just the current rabbit trail i'm following.

Thanks for any/all help you can provide.